# Create automatically table that is composed by its primary key and 2 other foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have table A with a primary id, 
a table B with a primary key id also and another 
table C with a primary key id and rows Aid and Bid where Aid and Bid are foreign keys of C and the primary keys of A and B respectively.

One way of populating these DB would be populating table A, table B and table C separately.

I would like to know if there is a more clever way of doing it, where I could populate A first and at the same time I populate B, I can indicate that an entry in C should be also created.

Any idea and suggestion on how to populate them is welcome. I'm trying to take advantage of the foreign keys structure.

Thanks.

Comment: A sequel to another question for deleting rows from the table A for the same schema. You might consider asking the bigger question at a go to get a better approach.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.. How do you know, which Aid and Bid should be grouped together in table C ?
If you use two unique foreign keys in table C, you need no additional primary key there as far as I know

Comment: Tobias, I thought about when inserting a row into B, I could indicate an Aid. This might not be possible. I'm just trying to find the best way to do it. Is there a way of inserting an entry on A and B at the same time and indicate to create an entry on C. The insert statement AFAIK only allows inserting rows in one table at a time not multiple, rigt?

Comment: UPDATE: Let me explain better the situation: I have many columns in the tables A and B. Their id is set to AUTO_INCREMENT. So when I insert rows in table A and B, I don't have access to their keys. To create the table C, I need them. So I would like to know if there was a way of telling mysql how to associate their foreign keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) that will analyze your structure and create this for your. Examples of ORMs are:

- For PHP:

  - [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)
- For .NET

  - [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)
  - [There are a lot more of them](http://www.theserverside.net/news/thread.tss?thread_id=29914)
- For Java:

  - [Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/)
  - [Apache Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/)
  - [..] And a lot more

You can find a pretty decent [list of ORMs here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#PHP).

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Python, but i'm not familiar with ORMs. I'm afraid that setting it up and leaning it would be more expensive than implementing it in the simplest way (every table separately)